# Composer.lock in library

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an application using Composer here at work, and we commit the composer.lock file so our dev and prod are the same.  But when creating a library that is installed by composer, should I commit the composer.lock file for the library as well?  Or will that cause problems for our internal repo or for composer itself?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It won't cause any issue because the composer.lock is only used when you actually run composer install within the library's root directory. When it is installed as a dependency the dependencies' lock files are never taken into account.

That said, for libraries it indeed does not really make sense to commit a lock file, so feel free to .gitignore it. We just say to always commit it because that is what 99% of the people should do. If some library authors know better and ignore it in their libs that's fine, but it does not really matter either way.

Comment: Library maintainers will "run composer install within the library's root directory" when they're working on the library itself. They often find it useful to have the same version of e.g. phpcs or phpunit installed (require-dev more often than not, but still useful to have locked).

Maybe you could clarify why it "does not really make sense"? I can only think of situations where there is literally nothing being locked.

Answer (score 7):

It's worth putting the `composer.lock` in a library for the same reason that you would put it in deployable projects; to allow you develop and test the library against exactly the same  dependencies that were used in it's development.

This would be useful for your automated testing of libraries, as well as helping to quickly identify whether bugs in the library are caused either by a an actual bug in the library itself, or a bug/changed behaviour in one of it's dependencies. Or to put it more colloquially it help avoids the 'works for me' problem.

As Seldaek said, the `composer.lock` file for a library is not passed up to be used by a project that merely requires that library. It is only used when you are running composer in the root of the library.

So with a small benefit of adding it, and with no downside, I'd recommend adding it.

Comment: I suppose it is useful when you want to have reproducible builds in your library.